# Angular problemas con la navegación entre componentes

Tags: javascript, angular, rutas, angular-router

Estoy realizando una aplicación con angular, la misma tiene un listado de productos y si doy click en cualquiera de los productos me lleva a la pagina individual de cada uno.

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card-columns mt-3">
    <div class="card" *ngFor="let i of contenido; let b = index;" style="width: 18rem">
      <img  src= "{{i.img}}" class="card-img-top img-fluid" alt="card image cap" id="img" />
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">{{i.casa}} <a href="#" class="badge badge-success">  Nuevo</a></h5>
        <p class="card-text">{{i.descrip}}</p>
        <h6>Valor {{i.valor}}</h6>
        <button [routerLink]="['/producto',b]" class="btn btn-primary">Ver Casa</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ahora creo un método llamado *getcasa*, el cual recibe un numero como parámetro y hace un *return* de uno de los objetos que contiene el array de objetos llamado contenido:

```
getcasa(b: number): Content {
  return this.contenido[b];
}
```

Ahora en el componente del producto individual, llamo al servicio (contenido) y obtengo el parámetro. Una vez que ya tengo el valor del parámetro que recibo por url (que es de tipo number), se lo paso como parámetro al método *getcasa* y lo alojo en la propiedad casa.

```
this.ruta.params.subscribe(params => {
  this.casa = this.contenido.getcasa(params['id']);
});
```

Luego hago la interpolación en el template del componente:

```
<div class = "col-md-4">
<img src="{{casa.img}}" class="img-fluid" alt="">
<br/>
<h3>Casa {{casa.casa }}</h3>
<h3 class="mt-3">{{casa.valor}}</h3>
<i class="fas fa-credit-card"></i><a routerLink="/contacto" > Ver medios de pago</a>
<button routerLink="/contacto" *ngIf="casa.condicion === 'alquilar'" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-block col-md-4 mt-2">Reservar</button>
<button routerLink="/contacto" *ngIf="casa.condicion === 'reservar'" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-block col-md-4 mt-2">Contactar</button>
</div>
```

**Es aquí donde comienza el problema:** En el template del producto quiero colocar una div que tenga 6 cards , bajo el titulo te puede interesar, para eso en el servicio realicé un método el cual filtra los objetos que tengan como condición alquilar y luego si esos objetos no tienen la misma imagen que el producto, los colocará dentro de un nuevo array llamado filtro:

```
getalquiler(casa: any = {}) {
const ventas = this.contenido.filter((obj) => obj.condicion === 'alquilar');
ventas.forEach(element => {
  if (element.img !== casa.img) {
    this.filtro.push(element);
  }
});
return this.filtro;}
```

Ahora en el componente del producto  llamo a este servicio y le paso como parámetro la propiedad casa, con el fin de que en el template del producto individual no se muestren dos objetos con la misma imagen.

```
this.alquiler = this.contenido.getalquiler(this.casa);
```

Ahora hago la interpolación de la propiedad alquiler en el template y funciona bien:

```
<h4 *ngIf="casa.condicion === 'alquilar'">Te puede interesar  <hr/></h4>
  <div class="card-columns mt-3" *ngIf="casa.condicion === 'alquilar'">
    <div class="card" *ngFor="let i of alquiler; let b = index;" style="width: 18rem">
      <img  src= "{{i.img}}" class="card-img-top img-fluid" alt="card image cap" id="img" />
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">{{i.casa}} <a href="#" class="badge badge-success">  Nuevo</a></h5>
        <p class="card-text">{{i.descrip}}</p>
        <h6>Valor {{i.valor}}</h6>
        <button [routerLink]="['/producto',b]" class="btn btn-primary">Ver Casa</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Pero **el problema ocurre** cuando le doy click a cualquiera de estas cards de la sección te puede interesar , ya que si bien me dirige a la pagina individual del producto , pero no me respeta el método de que impide colocar en el template dos objetos con la misma imagen.

> Disculpen por tanto texto, quiero explicar el problema de forma más detallada pero tengo temor a distraerlos o a que se pierda el problema entre tantas palabras.

Answer (score 0):

Si no he entendido mal, en realidad todo el problema se reduce a que el filtro no parece funcionar:

```
getalquiler(casa: any = {}) {
  const ventas = this.contenido.filter((obj) => obj.condicion === 'alquilar');
  ventas.forEach(element => {
    if (element.img !== casa.img) {
      this.filtro.push(element);
    }
  });
  return this.filtro;
}
```

Asumiendo que la propiedad `img` es un string, me parece que podrías usar el método filter para obtener lo que quieres:

```
getAlquiler(casa: any = {}) {
  const filtro = this.contenido.filter((obj) => {
    return obj.condicion === 'alquilar' && obj.img !== casa.img;
  return filtro;
}
```

Comment: Mi método si funciona , tu respuestas es lo mismo que mi metodo pero simplificado , te agradezco . EL PROBLEMA OCURRE cuando  presiono click en algunas de las cards de la sección "te puede interesar", si bien me redirige a la pagina individual de la card, pero no me cumple con la funcion de filtrado.